# inserting an iframe into angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I've got an app with a list of videos, I don't want to load all the videos at once, just when the user selects a video and then selects play (yes, it's a two step process).

So when the user selects a video, I am trying to embed only the iframe player for that video into the selected element.

In my controller, I have

```
$scope.selectedVideo = function(index){
        if($scope.activeVideo===index)return; // preventing bubbling from closeSelected (I hope)
        if($scope.activeVideo !== null){
            $scope.closeSelected();
        }
        var video = $scope.videos[index];
        video.embed = '<span><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed'+video.id+'"></iframe> does something show?</span>';
        video.active = true;
        $scope.activeVideo=index;
    }
```

and in my html, I have

```
<div ng-bind-html="video.embed"></div>
```

I've tried all manner of `ng-bind-html-unsafe` (which I think is deprecated), but nothing is actually putting the iframe into the page.

I'm using angular version 1.2.15, and I have ngSanitize included in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this wrong. That said if you really want to output html like you're trying to, ng-bind-html-unsafe is deprecated like you state. The new way of doing it is to inject $sce and use `trustAsHtml`

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)

You can make a filter like this:

```
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', 
    function($sce) {
        return function(val) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        };
    }
]);
```

And then in your HTML do this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="video.embed | unsafe"></div>
```

Not sure if `video` is really part of the scope? But really it sounds like you're doing it wrong. Have you tried using a ng-view instead? That way you can swap the content of that view (the content being an iframe).

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Hope it helps!

Comment: That did the trick, though I am curious as to why you that I was going about it the right way. If I'm loading 50 videos onto the page, I don't want every one of those videos embedded into the page, as the iframe downloads the page even if the iframe is hidden.

Comment: The view is kinda like a placeholder for dynamic content but with its own life - the view can be an iframe and its properties (like src) can be bound though a controller and scope. You can do SPA (single page application) with ngView kinda like server-side masterpages or razor layout pages (microsoft termonology, sorry)